# Python convert integer list to integer

Tags: python, dictionary, type-conversion, int, integer

How can i convert for ex. `x = [0, 25, 303, 4]` to integer, not a list, without losing 0 at the beginning?
I tried with `print(int(''.join(map(str,x))))` but the output was without 0.

It has to be done with 'return' not 'print' - i have to save it into .txt file.

My expected output is '0253034'.

Comment: an integer will not have a leading 0, but you could format it as a string

Comment: What do you mean by "convert to integer"? What's your expected result given the `x` in your question?

Comment: thanks for response! my expected result is 0253034. it has to be done with 'return' not 'print', because i have to save it into .txt file

Comment: just take out `int`. Since you're just saving to a `txt` file, it probably doesn't need to be `int` type. `''.join(map(str,x))`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just **concatenate the list** simply u can do like this:

```
lst = [0, 25,303,4] 
for i in lst: 
    print(i, end="")
```

Output:

```
0253034
```

or

```
def convertor(lis):
  a=''
  for i in lis:
    a=a+str(i)
  return a  

lst = [0, 25,303,4] 
print(convertor(lst))
```

Comment: thanks for response! unfortunately it has to be done with 'return' not 'print', because i have to save it into .txt file

Comment: u can also write a function to return that check out my answer. @poloOlo